# Обнуляются ли static поля после уничтожения всех экземпляров класса?

Tags: java, android

Есть задача: запускать поток(Thread1) 1 раз и только. При этом, другой поток(Thread2) периодически создает нужный поток(Thread1). Из за невозможности контролировать количество, происходит повторение действий. Как решить красиво и правильно я не знаю.

Главный вопрос. Имеем

```
 static Thread myThread;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (myThread != null) {
                    if (isAlive()) {
                        // Если поток есть, и живой, то return.
                        // Т.е. получается поток создался, 
                        // но не делая ничего завершился, 
                        // а предыдущий, который еще работает.... дорабатывает.
                        return;
                    }
                }
            // Если не было return, то поток работает
            }
```

Но, я переживаю что произойдет следующее: в потоке код выполняется в while(true) {}, т.е. постоянно. На android. И если из за нехватки памяти или другим причинам ОС она прибьет мой поток(Thread1), то другой поток(Thread2) создает его заново. Происходит код выше, и если static Thread myThread не обнулится, то получится что и не работает нужный поток и другие не смогут начать работу. Метода onDestroy нет не у Thread, не у Runnable интерфейса.

Возможно я предложил очень "некрасивое" решение и делается это совсем не так, если кто знает, подскажите в каком направлении смотреть. Я не совсем понимаю природу работы сборщика мусора в java, и политики работы ОС Android(причины завершить процесс аварийно и т.д.).

P.S. Вопрос вкратце: должен жить 1 поток либо ни одного. Если ни одного нет, иметь возможность запустить 1.

UDP: Такой код вроде работает, не знаю как будет вести себя в нестандартных ситуациях.

```
public static Thread myThread;

     @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            if (myThread == null) {
                myThread = new Thread(new TaskExecutor(this));
                myThread.start();
            } else {
                if (!myThread.isAlive()) {
                    myThread = new Thread(new TaskExecutor(this));
                    myThread.start();
                }
            }
            return START_STICKY;
        }
```

Первый вариант что я писал, там почему то не срабатывает this.isAlive() внутри потока уже. Возвращает false;

UPD 2: 
Eugene Krivenja ответ хороший. Но Создавая поток при пересоздании сервиса получается так: Старый сервис создан, создал поток. Потом Сервис умирает (я его сам прибил), но поток функционирует. Сервис пере создается, создает поток - имеем 2 рабочих потока, которые дублируют действия. Статик переменная решила мою проблему, но как ты сказал могут быть необъяснимые действия. Буду думать дальше, как сделать 100% безопасно.

Comment: могу предположить, что обнуление статической переменной произойдёт одновременно с убийством потока. Пока есть переменная, поток не уничтожит GC (он держится на переменной). Пока есть поток, смысла уничтожать переменную нет. Но лучше подождать ответа специалиста. А вы учитываете что 2 поток тоже может вылететь по нехватке памяти к примеру? И может тогда лучше 1 поток в сервис преобразовать?

Comment: В сервисе ведь все равно необходимо запускать отдельный поток, потому что while(true) {} блокирует UI.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Хранить что-либо в статических переменных на Андроид очень не рекомендуется. Могут происходить труднообьяснимые вещи. Все из-за механизма выгрузки-загрузки классов.

Стандартный подход в вашем случае, создать потомка от класса `Application` и в нем хранить ссылку (не статическую) на поток, а сам поток создавать в `onCreate()`.
В этом случае поток система уничтожит вместе с обьектом `Application`, а при перезапуске приложения `Application` создается самым первым, соответсвенно и поток будет создан.

Второй вариант с сервисом рабочий, и наверное предпочтительный, только `myThread` опять же не должен быть статическим и поток уничтожится только вместе с сервисом. Поэтому не стоить перезапускать поток кем-то извне, надо перезапускать сам сервис.

Как-то так. На Андроид кроме констант в статических переменных лучше ничего вообще не иметь.