# Контроль потоков в Android

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Стояла задача. Есть android приложение, service запускает поток. После того как android прибьет service, поток может работать. Service перезапускается, создает второй поток, а этого допускать нельзя.

Тут я пытался найти решение(использовать статик поле для хранения ссылки на поток): [Обнуляются ли static поля после уничтожения всех экземпляров класса?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523585/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-static-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0)
Там же мне сказали, что решение не надежное, т.к:

> Хранить что-либо в статических переменных на Андроид очень не
>   рекомендуется. Могут происходить труднообьяснимые вещи. Все из-за
>   механизма выгрузки-загрузки классов.

Сейчас написал все так:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Map<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> threads = Thread.getAllStackTraces();

    boolean isAlive = false;

    for (Thread thread : threads.keySet()) {
        if (thread.getName().equals("myThread")) 
             if (thread.isAlive())
                 isAlive = true;
        }

        if (!isAlive) {
            Task task = new Task(this);
            task.setName("myThread");
            task.start();
        }

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Главный вопрос: является ли данное решение безопасным, не проскочит ли второй поток? Потоки вероятнее будут закрываться android при не хватке памяти, будут закрываться service. Методов onDestroy нет ни в service, не в thread. И это не страшно, будет неприятно если Task запустится 2 раза.

P.S. Мне посоветовали использовать singleton для класса потока, но там, опять же используются статик поля.

UPD: Дико извиняюсь, метод onDestroy у сервиса есть, просто я помню, где то была информация, что в android он может не сработать, потому что сервис прибивается мгновенно. Мне это кажется неправильным, но и проверить я это не могу.

Так же, в сервисе я вынужден создать поток для http. Опять же, где хранить ссылку на поток, если он должен работать до последнего, даже если сервис прекращает работу, а когда сервис запускается заново, необходимо проверить, живет ли поток. Но в статик переменных я опасаюсь хранить ссылку.

UDP 2: Перебирать все варианты бессмысленно,   т.к. их очень много. Главное, в приложении случилась ситуация, когда создалось два потока. А этого допускать нельзя. На данный момент приложение работает 2ой день и поток существует в 1 экземпляре. Когда я полагался на то, что завершив сервис, завершиться и поток, я получил 3 потока повторяющих одни и те же операции.

В syncronized я не силен, но мне кажется это не то.

Comment: По-моему, нет гарантии, что новый поток не "проскочит" даже пока выполняется `getAllStackTraces`. Но у вас же вроде сервис, фреймворк обещает, что может существовать только один экземпляр объекта службы.

Comment: С чего это вы взяли что у сервиса нет метода `onDestroy`? Он есть и именно там нужно освобождать все занятые им ресурсы, включая потоки.

Comment: а `synchronized` использовать не получится?

Comment: Речь идет о low memory? Как android может прибить сервис (или activity), не прибив процесс? Если android прибьет процесс, то прибьются и все потоки, относящиеся к этому процессу.