# Утечка памяти ли это? Как исправить?

Tags: java, android, утечка-памяти

### Что использую?

Пишу Android приложение с использованием таких библиотек:

- Мoxy (Для реализации архитектуры MVP)
- RxJava (Для удобной работы с данными)
- Socket.io (Конкретно моя реализация RxSocket под RxJava)
- Ну и многие другие (ButterKnife и для тестов)

---

### Что делаю?

У меня есть UI: `Fragments` и `Activities` и для каждого реализован `Presenter`

[image: View не показываю, ибо не поместится на фотографии]

Зайдем в `Presenter` (`AuthActivity`), эта активность запускается в первую очередь, значит и её `Presenter` тоже.

Здесь у нас вот такой код:

```
@InjectViewState
public class AuthPresenter extends MvpPresenter<AuthView> 
{
    public RxSocket socket;

    private AuthView view;

    public AuthPresenter() 
    {
        // Синглтон, код синглтона будет ниже
        socket = SingletonSocket.getInstance(); 

        view = getViewState();
    }

    public void authServer(){
        socket.connect()
                .subscribe(() -> {
                    listenForErrors();
                    view.showAuthFragment();
                }, throwable -> {
                    view.showErrorFragment(null);
                    throwable.printStackTrace();

                });
    }

    private void listenForErrors(){
        socket.on(Socket.EVENT_ERROR)
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(objects -> {
                    view.showError("Ошибка подключения");
                    view.showErrorFragment(null);
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();        
        socket.off(Socket.EVENT_ERROR);          
    }
}
```

`RxSocket` socket идет инициализация через синглтон:

```
public final class SingletonSocket 
{

    private static RxSocket socket;

    private SingletonSocket(){}

    public static RxSocket getInstance(){
        if(socket == null){
            IO.Options options = new IO.Options();
            options.transports = new String[]{"websocket"};
            options.reconnection = false;
            options.forceNew = false;
            socket = new RxSocket(Constants.URL, options);
        }
        return socket;
    }
}
```

Он нужен для одноразового коннекта.

Далее этот синглтон через конструктор `Presenter` каждого `Fragment`, чтобы потом из фрагментов получать нужные данные с сервера.

### В чём проблема? №1

Я заметил, что когда я перехожу на вторую активность (при этом уничтожаю старую), и далее нажимаю физическую кнопку назад, то у меня все закрывается (Что правильно), но при повторном открытии из недавних приложений открывается первая активность. И при этом фрагмент уже не показывается (видимо синглтон выжил) Правильно ли это?

Это еще не все, с каждой сменой фрагмента память поднимается (методом `replace`)

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        RegisterFirstFragment fragment = new RegisterFirstFragment(); //Здесь класс фрагмента, в который я хочу перейти
        transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.fragment_slide_left_anim, R.animator.fragment_slide_right_anim);
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        transaction.remove(this); //Здесь я пытался уничтожить фрагмент
        transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

17мб -> 18мб -> 19мб -> 20мб и GG не собирает старые не нужные фрагменты.

### В чём проблема? №2

Также у меня в каждом фрагменте есть SnackBar, который вызывается в случае неверных данный введенных пользователем и с каждым его вызовом у меня память увеличивается и не очищается. Не понимаю как в таком случае освобождать память?

### Так в чем же дело?

Вопрос такой - является ли это повышение памяти нормальным, если нет, как в моем случае это можно исправить?

---

### Общие вопросы

Статических переменных, которые хранят контекст у меня нет ни в одном классе.
Может быть проблема в синглтоне? 
Как после нажатия кнопки назад на последней `Activity` уничтожить и синглтон?

Заранее спасибо, за все предложенные решения и **рекомендации**(Например, если я что-то делаю не так, или нужен, также например, другой паттерн и т.д.).

Comment: Попробуйте https://github.com/square/leakcanary

Comment: @post_zeew Она у меня подключена, но ведь библиотека не поможет исправить утечку

Comment: Она поможет ее найти.

Comment: То есть если она не говорит, значит утечки нет?

Comment: Про LeakCanary правильно подмечено, и если вы ее подключили как надо, то скорее всего утечек нет.

Comment: По поводу синглтонов в Андроид, я уже пару раз высказывался: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523585/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-static-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0/523633#523633, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488660/singleton-%D0%B2-android-%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE/488737#488737

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Спасибо за информацию, но насчет вот этого повышения памяти. Это нормально?

Comment: Мне сложно судить заочно, посмотрите в профайлере, сколько памяти при запуске, сколько на пике использования, сколько после выхода и сколько соберет GC после этого, если его принудительно запустить. Если видно явно, он что-то собирает и LeakCanary молчит, скорее всего все Ок.

Comment: в профайлере можно посмотреть сколько инстансов любой сущности в памяти в данный момент и кто держит на них ссылку. https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler.html#capture-heap-dump вот посмотрите сколько у вас инстансов фрагмента и кто их держит, предварительно запустите GC

Answer (score 1):

Думаю надо отписывать от подписки в onDestroy

```
subscription = socket.connect()
                .subscribe(...)

....

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();        
    socket.off(Socket.EVENT_ERROR);

    if (subscription != null) {
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    }      
}
```