# kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property db has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin

Я новичок в разработке Android, пожалуйста, помогите. У меня есть RecyclerView — в нем есть список элементов, напротив каждого из которых есть возможность добавить его в избранное.

При нажатии на ImageButton вызывается метод updateAddToFavourite, который должен обновить данные о записи в базе данных (изменить значение в столбце с 0 на 1), но когда я запускаю приложение и нажимаю кнопку add_to_favorite, получаю ошибку:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.foodmap, PID: 20133 kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property db has not been initialized at com.example.foodmap.MainActivity.getDb(MainActivity.kt:30) at com.example.foodmap.MainActivity.updateAddToFavourite(MainActivity.kt:230) at com.example.foodmap.ProductAdapter.onBindViewHolder$lambda$0(ProductAdapter.kt:49) at com.example.foodmap.ProductAdapter.$r8$lambda$2q2XJ3l7i7sA7ZsUTOGFIU09fiQ(Unknown Source:0) at com.example.foodmap.ProductAdapter$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:4) at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7542) at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7519) at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0) at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29476) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7918) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.foodmap

import android.content.Intent
import android.database.Cursor
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.foodmap.DatabaseHelper
import com.example.foodmap.DatabaseHelper.columnProducts_id
import com.example.foodmap.DatabaseHelper.columnSafetyIndicator
import com.example.foodmap.DatabaseHelper.tableProducts
import com.example.foodmap.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.AccountHeader
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.AccountHeaderBuilder
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.Drawer
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.DrawerBuilder
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.PrimaryDrawerItem
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.ProfileDrawerItem
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.interfaces.IDrawerItem

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnItemClickListener {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var databaseHelper: DatabaseHelper
    lateinit var db: SQLiteDatabase
    private lateinit var productCursor: Cursor
    private lateinit var fodmapCursor: Cursor
    private lateinit var productAdapter: ProductAdapter
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var mDrawer: Drawer
    private lateinit var mHeader: AccountHeader
    private lateinit var mToolbar: Toolbar
    private val TAG = "MainActivity" // костыль чтобы вызвать метод из MainActivity

    private fun initial() {
        recyclerView = binding.rvProducts
        productAdapter = ProductAdapter(myProducts(), this)
        recyclerView.adapter = productAdapter
        mToolbar = binding.mainToolbar
    }

    private fun initFunc() {
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar)
        createHeader()
        createDrawer()
    }

    private fun createDrawer() {
        mDrawer =
            DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withToolbar(mToolbar)
                .withActionBarDrawerToggle(true)
                .withSelectedItem(-1)
                .withAccountHeader(mHeader)
                .addDrawerItems(
                    PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(1)
                        .withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                        .withName("Профиль пользователя")
                        .withSelectable(false),
                    PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(2)
                        .withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                        .withName("Мой дневник")
                        .withSelectable(false),
                    PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(3)
                        .withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                        .withName("Мои продукты")
                        .withSelectable(false),
                    PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(4)
                        .withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                        .withName("Мои рецепты")
                        .withSelectable(false),
                    PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(5)
                        .withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                        .withName("Выход")
                        .withSelectable(false)
                ).withOnDrawerItemClickListener(object : Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener {
                    override fun onItemClick(
                        view: View?,
                        position: Int,
                        drawerItem: IDrawerItem<*>
                    ): Boolean {
                        val newIntent = Intent(this@MainActivity, SelectedProducts::class.java)

                        when (position) {
                            3 -> startActivity(newIntent)
                        }
                        return false
                    }
                }).build()
    }

    private fun createHeader() {
        mHeader = AccountHeaderBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.header)
            .addProfiles(
                ProfileDrawerItem()
                    .withName("Денис Белозёров")
                    .withIcon(R.drawable._avatar180)
                    .withEmail("denis.belozerov@edu.hse.ru")
            )
            .build()
    }

    private fun myProducts(): ArrayList<ProductModel> {
        val productList = ArrayList<ProductModel>()
        val count: Int = productCursor.count

        var i = 0
        while (i < count) {
            var colorSafety = getColor(R.color.green) // храним цвет каждого продукта

            productCursor.moveToPosition(i)
            val nameProduct: String =
                productCursor.getString(productCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.columnProductsName))
            val categoryProduct: String =
                productCursor.getString(productCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.columnCategoryName))
            val safetyIndicator: String =
                productCursor.getString(productCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.columnSafetyIndicator))

            when (safetyIndicator) {
                "Безопасен" -> colorSafety = getColor(R.color.green)
                "Небезопасен" -> colorSafety = getColor(R.color.red)
                "Умеренно безопасен" -> colorSafety = getColor(R.color.yellow)
            }

            productList.add(ProductModel(nameProduct, categoryProduct, colorSafety))
            i++
        }
        return productList
    }

    private fun createAlertDialog(
        title: String,
        olygos: String,
        fructose: String,
        polyols: String,
        lactose: String,
        weight: String
    ) {
        val productDialogView =
            LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_alert_dialog_info_products_1, null)
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(productDialogView).setTitle(title)

        val textViewWeight: TextView = productDialogView.findViewById(R.id.Product_weight_1_1_1)
        val textViewOlygos: TextView = productDialogView.findViewById(R.id.Olygos_1_1_2)
        val textViewFructose: TextView = productDialogView.findViewById(R.id.Fructose_1_1_3)
        val textViewPolyols: TextView = productDialogView.findViewById(R.id.Polyols_1_1_4)
        val textViewLactose: TextView = productDialogView.findViewById(R.id.Lactose_1_1_5)

        textViewWeight.setText(weight + " гр")
        textViewOlygos.setText(olygos)
        textViewFructose.setText(fructose)
        textViewPolyols.setText(polyols)
        textViewLactose.setText(lactose)

        builder.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, which ->
        }
        builder.show()
    }

    override fun onItemClicked(product: ProductModel) {
        val queryFodmap =
            "SELECT Продукты._id, Продукты.[Название продукта], Продукты.[Наличие глютена], FODMAP.[Единицы измерения гр], FODMAP.[Наличие Olygos (олигосахариды)], FODMAP.[Наличие Fructose (фруктоза)], FODMAP.[Наличие Polyols (полиолы)], FODMAP.[Наличие Lactose (лактоза)] FROM Продукты INNER JOIN FODMAP ON Продукты.[Название продукта] = FODMAP.[Название продукта] WHERE Продукты.[Название продукта] = \"${product.product}\""
        fodmapCursor = db.rawQuery(queryFodmap, null)
        fodmapCursor.moveToFirst()
        val itemOlygos =
            fodmapCursor.getString(fodmapCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.columnFodmapOlygos)) // извлекаем характеристики продукта и передаем в AlertDialog
        val itemFructose =
            fodmapCursor.getString(fodmapCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.columnFodmapFructose))
        val itemPolyols =
            fodmapCursor.getString(fodmapCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.columnFodmapPolyols))
        val itemLactose =
            fodmapCursor.getString(fodmapCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.columnFodmapLactose))
        val itemWeight =
            fodmapCursor.getString(fodmapCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.columnFodmapUnit))
        createAlertDialog(
            "${product.product}",
            itemOlygos,
            itemFructose,
            itemPolyols,
            itemLactose,
            itemWeight
        )
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper(applicationContext)
        databaseHelper.create_db()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        db = databaseHelper.open()

        val queryProducts =
            "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.tableProducts + " INNER JOIN " + DatabaseHelper.tableCategory + " ON " + "Продукты.[Категория продукта] = Категория.[Код категории]"
        val queryFodmap =
            "SELECT Продукты._id, Продукты.[Название продукта], Продукты.[Наличие глютена], FODMAP.[Единицы измерения гр], FODMAP.[Наличие Olygos (олигосахариды)], FODMAP.[Наличие Fructose (фруктоза)], FODMAP.[Наличие Polyols (полиолы)], FODMAP.[Наличие Lactose (лактоза)]\n" +
                    "FROM Продукты INNER JOIN FODMAP ON Продукты.[Название продукта] = FODMAP.[Название продукта]"

        productCursor = db.rawQuery(queryProducts, null)
        fodmapCursor = db.rawQuery(queryFodmap, null)

        initial()
        initFunc()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        db.close()
        productCursor.close()
    }

    companion object {
        val instance = MainActivity()
    }

    fun updateAddToFavourite(position: Int) {
        db = databaseHelper.open()
        db.execSQL("UPDATE ${DatabaseHelper.tableProducts} SET ${DatabaseHelper.columnSafetyIndicator} = 1 WHERE ${DatabaseHelper.columnProducts_id} == $position")
    }
}
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
package com.example.foodmap;

import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH;
    private static String DB_NAME = "fodmap.db";
    private static final int SCHEMA = 1;
    static final String tableProducts = "Продукты";
    static final String columnProducts_id = "_id";
    static final String columnProductsName = "Название продукта";
    static final String columnProductsCode = "Код продукта";
    static final String columnProductsCategory = "Категория продукта";
    static final String columnProductsGluten = "Наличие глютена";
    static final String columnProductsProtein = "Содержание белков (на 100 гр)";
    static final String columnProductsFats = "Содержание жиров (на 100 гр)";
    static final String columnProductsCarb = "Содержание углеводов (на 100 гр)";
    static final String columnSafetyIndicator = "Индикатор безопасности";

    static final String tableCategory = "Категория";
    static final String columnCategoryCode = "Код категории";
    static final String columnCategoryName = "Название категории";

    static final String tableFODMAP = "FODMAP";
    static final String columnFodmapProducts = "Название продукта";
    static final String columnFodmapUnit = "Единицы измерения гр";
    static final String columnFodmapOlygos = "Наличие Olygos (олигосахариды)";
    static final String columnFodmapFructose = "Наличие Fructose (фруктоза)";
    static final String columnFodmapPolyols = "Наличие Polyols (полиолы)";
    static final String columnFodmapLactose = "Наличие Lactose (лактоза)";

    private Context myContext;

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, SCHEMA);
        this.myContext = context;
        DB_PATH = context.getFilesDir().getPath() + DB_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) { }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,  int newVersion) { }

    void create_db(){

        File file = new File(DB_PATH);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            //получаем локальную бд как поток
            try(InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
                // Открываем пустую бд
                OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH)) {

                // побайтово копируем данные
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                myOutput.flush();
            }
            catch(IOException ex){
                Log.d("DatabaseHelper", ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    public SQLiteDatabase open()throws SQLException {
        return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
}
```

ProductAdapter.kt

```
package com.example.foodmap
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.foodmap.databinding.ItemProductsLayoutBinding

class MyHolder(val binding: ItemProductsLayoutBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    val name_product = binding.nameProduct
    val name_category = binding.categoryProduct
    val safety_indicator: ImageView = binding.safetyIndicator
    val add_to_favorite: ImageButton = binding.addToFavorite
    var buttonOn: Boolean = false

    fun bind(product: ProductModel, clickListener: OnItemClickListener) {
        name_product.text = product.product
        name_category.text = product.category
        safety_indicator.setColorFilter(product.safetyIndicator)

        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            clickListener.onItemClicked(product)
        }
    }
}

class ProductAdapter(
    private var products: ArrayList<ProductModel>,
    val itemClickListener: OnItemClickListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_products_layout, parent, false)
        return MyHolder(ItemProductsLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent,false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(myHolder: MyHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentPosition = products.get(position)
        myHolder.bind(currentPosition, itemClickListener)

        myHolder.binding.addToFavorite.setOnClickListener {
            if (!myHolder.buttonOn) {
                myHolder.buttonOn = true
                myHolder.add_to_favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_favorite_24)
                val getMainActivity = MainActivity.instance
                getMainActivity.updateAddToFavourite(position)

            } else {
                myHolder.buttonOn = false
                myHolder.add_to_favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_favorite_border_24)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return products.size
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun setList(list: ArrayList<ProductModel>) {
        products = list
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}

interface OnItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClicked(product: ProductModel)
}
```

item_products_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_product"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/no_image"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="2dp" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name_product"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="105dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon_product"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="Product"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/category_product"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="105dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon_product"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="Category"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/safety_indicator"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/add_to_favorite"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@color/red"
            app:civ_border_width="1dp"
            app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/add_to_favorite"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_favorite_border_24"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Что я делаю не так? Я понимаю, что db нужно инициализировать прежде чем обращаться к ней и она инициализируется в методе onResume, почему тогда указывает на то, что db не инициализирована?

Пытался переместить db = databaseHelper.open() в метод onCreate или onStart, но ошибка сохраняется.

Answer (score 0):

Вот от этого избавьтесь

```
companion object {
    val instance = MainActivity()
}
```

В результате вы из `ProductAdapter` через `instance` обращаетесь к другой `MainActivity`, в которой ничего не инициализировано.

Вы же передаете вторым параметром в конструктор `ProductAdapter` ссылку на активити, вот ей и пользуйтесь.

Статические ссылки на Context в Андроид разработке -- это зло.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/523633/184031
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/488737/184031